# Build QVariant list from non-ordered data

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qvariant

I have this set of data:

```
[ step:-1, name:"BaseName1",  value:v1 ]
[ step:-1, name:"BaseName2",  value:v2 ]
[ step:2,  name:"ParamName3", value:v3 ]
[ step:2,  name:"ParamName4", value:v4 ]
[ step:0,  name:"ParamName5", value:v5 ]
[ step:0,  name:"ParamName6", value:v6 ]
[ step:1,  name:"ParamName7", value:v7 ]
[ step:1,  name:"ParamName8", value:v8 ]
```

That I would like to convert to a QVariant, like this:

```
[
    "BaseName1": v1,
    "BaseName2": v2,
    "steps": [{
            "ParamName5": v5,
            "ParamName6": v6
        }, {
            "ParamName7": v7,
            "ParamName8": v8
        }, {
            "ParamName3": v3,
            "ParamName4": v4
        }
    ]
]
```

I figured it should be like this:

```
QVariantMap params;
params["Base_param_1"] = value;
params["Base_param_2"] = value2;
params["steps"] = QVariantList();
```

But for the array, I need the data to be ordered; which means I should insert step 0 in the `params["steps"]` *before* steps 1 and 3 (and step 2 should be empty).
Also, sorting the input data is not an option.

I tried to implement this with the following code:

```
struct Params{ 
    QString name;  
    QVariant value; 
    int step;/* -1 for base param */ 
};
QList<Params> _params = (...);

QVariantMap v_settings;
QVariantList v_steps;

for(int i=0; i<_params.size(); i++){
    const Param &param = _params[i];

    if( param.index == -1 ){
        v_settings.insert(param.name, param.value);
    }
    else {
        // if list too small, append empties to the list until it exists
        while( v_steps.size() < param.index ){
            QVariantMap map;
            v_steps.append(map);
        }

        v_steps.at(param.index).toMap().insert(param.name, param.value);
    }
}
v_settings.insert("steps", v_steps);
```

But the code fails at some point with an index out of bounds when encountering this line:

```
v_steps.at(param.index).toMap().insert(param.name, param.value);
```

So I guess my "fill with empty maps" loop failed somehow.
How should I do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues in your code.

"Index is out of bounds" issue happens because you didn't add enough objects to your list. You should write

```
while( v_steps.size() <= param.index ) {
```

i.e. replace `<` with `<=`. It will ensure that, e.g. 6 elements will be contained in the array before you access the 5th element (elements count from 0, remember?)

Another issue is in `toMap().insert`. `toMap()` returns `QMap` by value, not by reference. So there is no point in calling `insert` on it because it's just temporary value that has not been assigned to any variable. It will be destroyed immediately after `insert` ends, and no changes will be stored.

I suggest you to use `QVector<QVariantMap> v_steps` to store your data. `QVector` is better than `QList` in this case because it's easy to `resize()` it. Inserting can be done using the following code:

```
v_steps[param.index].insert(param.name, param.value);
```

Then you need to convert it to `QVariantList`:

```
QVariantList v_steps_real;
foreach(QVariantMap map, v_steps) {
  v_steps_real << map;
}
v_settings.insert("steps", v_steps_real);
```

Note that you can use `[]` operator instead of `insert()` to insert values into a map:

```
map["key"] = value;
```

Comment: That did the trick, thanks. I'm just wondering why there's no way to modify an array's content "in-place" for QtJson. It feels... incomplete.

Comment: You can do something like `QVariantMap map = variant_list[i].toMap(); map[key] = value;  variant_list[i] = map;` - it will edit QVariantMap in place. It causes some overhead, though.